# stripe confirmCardSetup successful, but I need the last4 digits expiration date and card type

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm following this [stripe tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse), and got to the point of calling `stripe.confirmCardSetup`, which works fine, but the object I get in response contains a lot of data:

```
cancellation_reason: null
client_secret: "seti_[cut]"
created: 1604679026
description: null
id: "seti_[seti]"
last_setup_error: null
livemode: false
next_action: null
object: "setup_intent"
payment_method: "pm_[cut]"
payment_method_types: ["card"]
status: "succeeded"
usage: "off_session"
```

I'd need to retrieve from it the last4 digits, the card brand, and expiration date, how would I go for it?

Answer (score 1):

The card brand, expiration, and last four digits are available on the PaymentMethod object linked to that SetupIntent:

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-brand
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-exp_month
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-exp_year
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-last4

Right now, the `confirmCardSetup` request only returns [the PaymentMethod ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/object#setup_intent_object-payment_method). So you need to make a request server-side to get the full PaymentMethod object using this endpoint here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/retrieve

At that point you can either trigger some server-side logic that uses those values, or you can send the information back to the frontend.